# OpenCV disparity output not making sense

Tags: python, opencv, stereo-3d

I've been experimenting with a homemade stereo camera, using a pair of webcams. I've taken several pictures and used OpenCV for calibration.

Rectified sample images:

[image: left image] [image: right image]

The calibration chessboards seem to be lined up horizontally.

But when I generate a disparity map based on [these instructions](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_depthmap/py_depthmap.html), the result seems meaningless.

[image]

My disparity-map code is fairly trivial:

```
stereo = cv2.StereoBM_create(numDisparities=16, blockSize=15)
disparity = stereo.compute(image_left, image_right)
cv2.imwrite(disparity, 'try2.ppm')
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should calibrate camera with different distance of calibration pattern images. then check the disparity map with different distance to camera and find best area.

Comment: I'll try this, but I'm not sure I understand why: do disparity maps only work within a certain range?

Comment: yes. depend on range of camera calibration and viewpoint of both camera. two camera have to see the object clearly.